# Matlab scatter plot with lowess curve

Tags: matlab, latex, scatter-plot

I'm writing a research paper and want to plot something like this from my dataset

[image]

Basically it's a Matlab scatter plot with a lowess curve showing the average value at each bin

I've been searching Google for 2 days and couldn't find a solution or a piece of sample code to do that yet

Stack Overflow is now my last resort :)

Comment: I think [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19506-binned-scatter-plot) does pretty well what you are/were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest code I can come up with.  This assumes you have your data in x and y vectors.

```
%adjust bins accordingly, or add a line that calculates them based on range.
bins = -0.5:0.01:0.5;
nBins = length(bins);

for index = 1:(nBins-1)

  binVec = (x >= bins(index) & x < bins(index+1));
  lowess(index) = mean(y(binvec));

end
%note that bins are shifted by one half step.
plot(x,y,'.',bins+0.005,lowess,'--r');
```

It is possible to vectorize this, but it is not worth it.  At least the way I found would make it unreadable and marginally more efficient, if at all.

Comment: Does this work for you?  If so, can you please click to select it as the answer?

Comment: sorry Dustin, I don't know why my comment was interrupted, I mean I see your point, I was able to modify your code to come up w the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A rough answer, is, use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13352 to do the density scatter plot, and use `histc` in matlab to generate the lowess curve at an appropriate resolution, and use `hold plot` on your density plot to draw

Comment: Hi John, that's an elegant solution you have, however I find that smoothhist2D doesn't work with log-scale axis, which is my case. However I do like the use of histc to count the values in each bin, thanks for your 2cent :)